# displaying sum of all the fetched filed in mongodb-nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these following collections:

**masters** collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e3171af6dd4b53168f8a7b6"),
    "status": ["active"],
    "category": ["isDealer"],
    "mappedCustomers": [
        ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c15"),
        ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c16")
        ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c17")
    ],
    "phoneNo" : ########9,
    "name": "dealer 3",
    "dealerSAPCode": 63547860
}
```

**orders** collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95555"),
    "frequency" : "FR",
    "orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c15"),
    "submittedTo" : ObjectId("5e3171af6dd4b53168f8a7b6"),
    "orderCreatedForDate" : ISODate("2020-01-31T18:30:00Z"),
    "totalOrder" : [
        {
            "tradeCopies" : 110,
            "subscriptionCopies":7,
            "freeCopies" : 0,
            "institutionalCopies" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7c"),
            "publicationCode" : "TOI",
            "publicationName" : "Times of India",
            "editionName" : "chennai city",
            "productCode" : "TCE1"
        },
        {
            "tradeCopies" : 120,
            "subscriptionCopies":10,
            "freeCopies" : 0,
            "institutionalCopies" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7b"),
            "publicationCode" : "ET",
            "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
            "editionName" : "chennai city",
            "productCode" : "ECE1"
        }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a9890v1"),
    "frequency" : "FR",
    "orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c16"),
    "submittedTo" : ObjectId("5e3171af6dd4b53168f8a7b6"),
    "orderCreatedForDate" : ISODate("2020-01-31T18:30:00Z"),
    "totalOrder" : [
        {
            "tradeCopies" : 190,
            "subscriptionCopies":20,
            "freeCopies" : 3,
            "institutionalCopies" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7c"),
            "publicationCode" : "TOI",
            "publicationName" : "Times of India",
            "editionName" : "chennai city",
            "productCode" : "TCE1"
        },
        {
            "tradeCopies" : 130,
            "subscriptionCopies":10,
            "freeCopies" : 2,
            "institutionalCopies" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7b"),
            "publicationCode" : "ET",
            "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
            "editionName" : "chennai city",
            "productCode" : "ECE1"  }
            ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e27f736a42d441fe8a8957d"),
    "frequency" : "FR",
    "orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c15"),
    "submittedTo" : ObjectId("5e3171af6dd4b53168f8a7b6"),
    "orderCreatedForDate" : ISODate("2020-01-24T18:30:00Z"),
    "totalOrder" : [
    {
        "tradeCopies" : 210,
        "subscriptionCopies":14,
        "freeCopies" : 0,
        "institutionalCopies" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7c"),
        "publicationCode" : "TOI",
        "publicationName" : "Times of India",
        "editionName" : "chennai city",
        "productCode" : "TCE1"
    },
    {
        "tradeCopies" : 310,
        "subscriptionCopies":17",
        "freeCopies" : 0,
        "institutionalCopies" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7b"),
        "publicationCode" : "ET",
        "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
        "editionName" : "chennai city",
        "productCode" : "ECE1"
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a9890h"),
    "frequency" : "FR",
    "orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e1ee75ba102a4638d195c16"),
    "submittedTo" : ObjectId("5e3171af6dd4b53168f8a7b6"),
    "orderCreatedForDate" : ISODate("2020-01-24T18:30:00Z"),
    "totalOrder" : [
    {
        "tradeCopies" : 100,
        "subscriptionCopies":20,
        "freeCopies" : 4,
        "institutionalCopies" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7c"),
        "publicationCode" : "TOI",
        "publicationName" : "Times of India",
        "editionName" : "chennai city",
        "productCode" : "TCE1"
    },
    {
        "tradeCopies" : 90,
        "subscriptionCopies:10,
            "freeCopies" :3 ,
    "institutionalCopies" : 1,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e293708683f4234a4a49e7b"),
    "publicationCode" : "ET",
    "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
    "editionName" : "chennai city",
    "productCode" : "ECE1"  }]
}
```

This is a sample of 4 documents from the orders collection with different dates(`orderCreatedForDate`)

Documents 1 and 2 are created for tomorrow's `orderorderCreatedForDate : ISODate("2020-01-31T18:30:00Z")` by different customers (`orderCreatedBy`).

Documents 3 and 4: `"_id":ObjectId("5e27f736a42d441fe8a8957d"),orderCreatedForDate : ISODate("2020-01-24T18:30:00Z")` was created on D-7th]

I need to do several things.

1. I need to show the sum of all {tradeCopies:300,subscriptionCopies:27,freeCopies,institutionalCopies } against the `productCode` for  all the mappedCustomers in the masters collection
2. I need to also show the sum of {tradeCopies,subscriptionCopies,freeCopies,institutionalCopies } for D-7th day in the above case where `orderCreatedForDate:ISODate("2020-01-24T18:30:00Z")`

This is the output I want:

```
{
    "totalOrder": [
        {
            "productCode": "TCE1",
            "tradeCopies": 300,
            "subscriptionCopies": 27,
            "freeCopies": 3,
            "institutionalCopies": 0,
            "publicationCode": "TOI",
            "publicationName": "Times of India",
            "editionName": "chennai city",
            "previousWeekCopies": [{
                "tradeCopies": 310, "subscriptionCopies": 34,
                "freeCopies": 4, "institutionalCopies": 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            "productCode": "ECE1",
            "tradeCopies": 250,
            "subscriptionCopies": 20,
            "freeCopies": 2,
            "institutionalCopies": 1,
            "publicationCode": "ET",
            "publicationName": "Economic Times",
            "editionName": "chennai city",
            "previousWeekCopies": [{
                "tradeCopies": 400, "subscriptionCopies": 27,
                "freeCopies": 3, "institutionalCopies": 1,
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please have a look at this if this can be achieved.

Comment: The given orders collection seems invalid. So its not getting imported. If you update the valid json data. Then we will proceed further

Comment: @ GokulaKannan T json data is valid help me out if you have found something ,that's the collection in the shell

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the aggregation pipeline.  Here is the code exported for Node:

```
    [
      {
        '$match': {
          '$or': [
            {
              'orderCreatedForDate': new Date('Fri, 31 Jan 2020 05:00:00 GMT')
            }, {
              'orderCreatedForDate': new Date('Fri, 24 Jan 2020 05:00:00 GMT')
            }
          ]
        }
      }, {
        '$unwind': {
          'path': '$totalOrder', 
          'includeArrayIndex': 'string'
        }
      }, {
        '$group': {
          '_id': {
            'productCode': '$totalOrder.productCode', 
            'date': '$orderCreatedForDate'
          }, 
          'tradeCopies': {
            '$sum': '$totalOrder.tradeCopies'
          }, 
          'subscriptionCopies': {
            '$sum': '$totalOrder.subscriptionCopies'
          }, 
          'freeCopies': {
            '$sum': '$totalOrder.freeCopies'
          }, 
          'institutionalCopies': {
            '$sum': '$totalOrder.institutionalCopies'
          }, 
          'productCode': {
            '$last': '$totalOrder.productCode'
          }, 
          'publicationName': {
            '$last': '$totalOrder.publicationName'
          }, 
          'editionName': {
            '$last': '$totalOrder.editionName'
          }, 
          'publicationDate': {
            '$last': '$orderCreatedForDate'
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$sort': {
          'publicationDate': 1
        }
      }, {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$_id.productCode', 
          'tradeCopies': {
            '$last': '$tradeCopies'
          }, 
          'previousTradeCopies': {
            '$first': '$tradeCopies'
          }, 
          'subscriptionCopies': {
            '$last': '$subscriptionCopies'
          }, 
          'previousSubscriptionCopies': {
            '$first': '$subscriptionCopies'
          }, 
          'institutionalCopies': {
            '$last': '$institutionalCopies'
          }, 
          'previousInstitutionalCopies': {
            '$first': '$institutionalCopies'
          }, 
          'freeCopies': {
            '$last': '$freeCopies'
          }, 
          'previousFreeCopies': {
            '$first': '$freeCopies'
          }, 
          'productCode': {
            '$last': '$productCode'
          }, 
          'publicationName': {
            '$last': '$publicationName'
          }, 
          'editionName': {
            '$last': '$editionName'
          }, 
          'publicationDate': {
            '$last': '$publicationDate'
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$project': {
          'productCode': 1, 
          'publicationName': 1, 
          'editionName': 1, 
          'publicationDate': 1, 
          'tradeCopies': 1, 
          'subscriptionCopies': 1, 
          'institutionalCopies': 1, 
          'freeCopies': 1, 
          'previousWeekCopies': [
            {
              'tradeCopies': '$previousTradeCopies', 
              'subscriptionCopies': '$previousSubscriptionCopies', 
              'freeCopies': '$previousFreeCopies', 
              'institutionalCopies': '$previousInstitutionalCopies'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Let's take a look at what is happening in each stage:

```
    [{$match: {
      $or: [ {orderCreatedForDate: ISODate('2020-01-31T05:00:00.000+00:00')},
      {orderCreatedForDate: ISODate('2020-01-24T05:00:00.000+00:00')}]
    }},
```

We begin by matching for orders that have the dates we care about.

```
    {$unwind: {
      path: "$totalOrder",
      includeArrayIndex: 'string'
    }},
```

Then we unwind the totalOrder array.  This creates a document for every order.

```
    {$group: {
      _id: {productCode: "$totalOrder.productCode", date: "$orderCreatedForDate"},
      tradeCopies: {
        $sum: "$totalOrder.tradeCopies"
      },
      subscriptionCopies: {
        $sum: "$totalOrder.subscriptionCopies"
      },
      freeCopies: {
        $sum: "$totalOrder.freeCopies"
      },
      institutionalCopies: {
        $sum: "$totalOrder.institutionalCopies"
      },
      productCode: { $last: "$totalOrder.productCode"},
      publicationName: { $last: "$totalOrder.publicationName"},
      editionName: { $last: "$totalOrder.editionName"},
      publicationDate: { $last: "$orderCreatedForDate"}
    }},
```

Then we group the documents by product code and date.  This allows us to generate the sums we need.

```
    {$sort: {
      publicationDate: 1
    }},
```

Then we sort our documents so we know that the older documents are first.

```
    {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.productCode",
      tradeCopies: {
        $last: "$tradeCopies"
      },
      previousTradeCopies: {
        $first: "$tradeCopies"
      },
      subscriptionCopies: {
        $last: "$subscriptionCopies"
      },
      previousSubscriptionCopies: {
        $first: "$subscriptionCopies"
      },
      institutionalCopies: {
        $last: "$institutionalCopies"
      },
      previousInstitutionalCopies: {
        $first: "$institutionalCopies"
      },
      freeCopies: {
        $last: "$freeCopies"
      },
      previousFreeCopies: {
        $first: "$freeCopies"
      },
      productCode: { $last: "$productCode"},
      publicationName: { $last: "$publicationName"},
      editionName: { $last: "$editionName"},
      publicationDate: { $last: "$publicationDate"}
    }},
```

Next we group our documents together by product code so we can create a single document for each product code.

```
    {$project: {
      productCode: 1,
      publicationName: 1,
      editionName: 1,
      publicationDate: 1,
      tradeCopies: 1,
      subscriptionCopies: 1,
      institutionalCopies: 1,
      freeCopies: 1,
      previousWeekCopies: [{
        tradeCopies: "$previousTradeCopies",
        subscriptionCopies: "$previousSubscriptionCopies",
        freeCopies: "$previousFreeCopies",
        institutionalCopies: "$previousInstitutionalCopies"
      }
        ]
    }}]
```

Finally, we project the fields we need in the format we need them.

Here are some screenshots so you can see visually what is happening in each stage. 
[image: agg pipeline visualization]
[image: agg pipeline visualization]

For more on how to use the aggregation pipeline with Node.js, see https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-analyze-data-using-the-aggregation-framework.  I also highly recommend MongoDB University's free course on the aggregation pipeline:  https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about

Comment: a big thanks :-) it took me a bit of time to understand but they way answered and explained that really helped me to understand a lot of things,, wanted to ask one more thing mappedCustomers in my masters collection , so i need to $unwind before $match query starts in your answer , i think that will find all the orders for all the mappedCutomers ...am i right ? and yes even your query is giving this output..tbc..

Comment: { "_id" : "TCE1", "tradeCopies" : 210, "subscriptionCopies" :0,"productCode" : "TCE1", "publicationName" : "Times of India", "publicationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z"), "previousWeekCopies" : [{ "tradeCopies" : 210, "subscriptionCopies" : 0,"freeCopies" : 0, "institutionalCopies" : 0}]}{ "_id" : "ECE1", "tradeCopies" : 310, "subscriptionCopies" : 0, "freeCopies" : 0, "productCode" : "ECE1", "publicationName" : "Economic Times","publicationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z"), "previousWeekCopies" : [ {"tradeCopies" : 310, "subscriptionCopies" : 0,}]} only 25th docs getting fetched

Comment: ....tbc  and sum of tradeCopes in previousWeekCopies is same..

Comment: If you want to connect fields from two collections,  you can use $lookup: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

I just took another look at my pipeline, and I'm not getting the same sum for 

tradeCopies:
_id:"ECE1"
institutionalCopies:1
freeCopies:2
productCode:"ECE1"
publicationDate:2020-01-31T05:00:00.000+00:00
subscriptionCopies:20
tradeCopies:250
publicationName:"Economic Times"
editionName:"chennai city"
previousWeekCopies:Array
0:Object
tradeCopies:400
subscriptionCopies:27
freeCopies:3
institutionalCopies:1