# $sum aggregation in mongodb nodej driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**collection 1: admin**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580"),
    "mappedcustomers": [
        ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c5"),
        ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c0"),
        ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c4")
    ],
    "phoneNo" : 9897654358,
    "name" : "acdbcs"
}
```

**collection 2: productOrders**

Tt has lots of documents, our concern is only for:

1. `"productOrderedForDate" : ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z")`[tomorrow order].
2. `"productOrderedForDate" : ISODate("2020-02-28T18:30:00Z")`[last week order]

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e27f998a42d441fe8a8957f"),
        "authorized": false,
        "orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c4"), // one of the mappedCustomer
        "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z"),// tomorrow Order
        "order": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a95110"),
            "productName": "Cups",
            "productCode": "CICE1",
            "size R": 21,
            "size L": 16
        },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a9510f"),
                "productName": "Bottles",
                "productCode": "BTCE1",
                "size R": 12,
                "size L": 3
            }]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0b90752b"),
        "authorized": false,
        "orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c0"),// another mappedCustomer
        "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z"),// tomorrow Order
        "order": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a87230"),
            "productName": "Cups",
            "productCode": "CICE1",
            "size R": 9,
            "size L": 7
        },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a8560e"),
                "productName": "Bottles",
                "productCode": "BTCE1",
                "size R": 3,
                "size L": 11
            }]

    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0b9876f"),
        "authorized": true,
        "orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c4"), // one of the mappedCustomer
        "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z"),// lastWeek order 
        "order": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a54220"),
            "productName": "Cups",
            "productCode": "CICE1",
            "size R": 2,
            "size L": 6
        },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a6520e"),
                "productName": "Bottles",
                "productCode": "BTCE1",
                "size R": 8,
                "size L": 16
            }]

    },
    {

        "_id": ObjectId("5e78f998a42d441fe898765d"),
        "authorized": true,
        "orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c0"), // another mappedCustomer
        "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z"),// lastWeek order 
        "order": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a87230"),
            "productName": "Cups",
            "productCode": "CICE1",
            "size R": 26,
            "size L": 19
        },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a8560f"),
                "productName": "Bottles",
                "productCode": "BTCE1",
                "size R": 4,
                "size L": 5
            }]
    }
]
```

This is what I have tried and have been able to unwind all mappedCustomers and according to that I have been able to find the orders created by them in orders collection below is the aggregation pipeline

```
db.admin.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: 'admin',
                localField: 'mappedCustomers',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'mappedCustomers'
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$mappedCustomers'
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$mappedCustomers"}
    },
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "orders",
                let: {mappedCustomersId: "$_id"},
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {$eq: ["$orderCreatedBy", "$$mappedCustomersId"]},
                            '$or': [
                                {
                                    'orderCreatedOn': ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z")
                                }, {
                                    'orderCreatedOn': ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z")
                                }]
                        }
                    }],
                as: "orders"
            }
    }, {
        $unwind: "orders"
    }
])
```

My problem is that I need to display the sum of all the `size R` and `size L` for all the `mappedCustomers` against the `productCode` mapped under that admin for tomorrow's date and previous week date i.e

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    orders : [
        {
            "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z"),
            "productName": "Cups",
            "productCode": "CICE1",
            "size R": 30,
            "size L": 23,
            "lastWeek": [{
                "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z"),
                "size R": 28,
                "size L": 25,
            }]
        }, {
            "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z"),
            "productName": "Bottles",
            "productCode": "BTCE1",
            "size R": 15,
            "size L": 14,
            "lastWeek": [{
                "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z"),
                "size R": 12,
                "size L": 21,
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

To Recap:
1. I will fetch the admin `id` from `req.body`.
2. I will find all customers mapped to `mappedCustomers`.
3. I will lookup from `orders` collections the orders that the `mappedCustomers` have created for the required dates.
4. I need to group all `size R` and `size L`.

I managed to do 1,2,3 but I'm unable to produce the required result for 4 and 5. Please have a look at it and tell me if this can be achieved.

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984579/displaying-sum-of-all-the-fetched-filed-in-mongodb-nodejs-driver/59987670?noredirect=1#comment106118859_59987670) post but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.admin.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "admin",
      localField: "mappedcustomers",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "mappedcustomers"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mappedcustomers"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$mappedcustomers"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      let: {
        mappedCustomersId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$orderCreatedBy",
                "$$mappedCustomersId"
              ]
            },
            "$or": [
              {
                "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z")
              },
              {
                "productOrderedForDate": ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z")
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$orders"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$orders.order"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$orders.order.productCode",
      orders: {
        $push: {
          productOrderedForDate: "$orders.productOrderedForDate",
          productName: "$orders.order.productName",
          productCode: "$orders.order.productCode",
          "size R": "$orders.order.size R",
          "size L": "$orders.order.size L"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      thisweek: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$orders",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.productOrderedForDate",
                  ISODate("2020-02-04T18:30:00Z")
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: {
            "size R": 0,
            "size L": 0
          },
          in: {
            productOrderedForDate: "$$this.productOrderedForDate",
            "productName": "$$this.productName",
            "productCode": "$$this.productCode",
            "size R": {
              $add: [
                "$$value.size R",
                "$$this.size R"
              ]
            },
            "size L": {
              $add: [
                "$$value.size L",
                "$$this.size L"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      lastWeek: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$orders",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.productOrderedForDate",
                  ISODate("2020-01-28T18:30:00Z")
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: {
            "size R": 0,
            "size L": 0
          },
          in: {
            productOrderedForDate: "$$this.productOrderedForDate",
            "size R": {
              $add: [
                "$$value.size R",
                "$$this.size R"
              ]
            },
            "size L": {
              $add: [
                "$$value.size L",
                "$$this.size L"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      orders: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$thisweek",
            {
              "lastWeek": [
                "$lastWeek"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ppwjKzJJi6M)